# How can i do some type of application tracking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

So i am not sure if i am able to explain this in the best way possible, but i will try my best. Lets say i have a very large node application or may be react application, and i want to keep track of how my different files are interacting with each other like there may be so many exports and imports of different functions or variables etc. Now i need to get info about all of this so that i can map out all of these things together so as to kind of make a schematic. Basically i want to do some type of tracking. Is there a way to solve this problem? I have only gotten to the part where i have listed down each and every file or folder in my project and thats it! It was quite easy to get up to here but dont know what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Discussion of instrumenting modules [here](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/339).

Comment: Are you using `require()` and `module.exports` or `import/export`?

Comment: i am using require( ), currently focused on node only.